# this.removeNum is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I've looked into all possibly similar cases and have applied their solutions, but still to no avail. I keep getting the not a function error for this.removeNum, every time I click on the X icon. Interestingly though, the addNum function is working fine, every time I click on the plus icon, not shown here; the only difference is that I'm creating the onClick attribute for the removeNum using DOM. The following is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        phoneCnt: 1
    };
    this.addNum = this.addNum.bind(this);
    this.removeNum = this.removeNum.bind(this);
}

removeNum() {
    console.log("test");
    console.log(this.state.phoneCnt);
    this.state.phoneCnt--;
    this.id.remove();
}

addNum() {
    // let divRemWrap = document.createElement("div");

    let divWrap = document.createElement("div");
    divWrap.classList.add("input--spacing");
    divWrap.setAttribute("id", `phone${this.state.phoneCnt}`);
    this.state.phoneCnt++;

    let numSpan = document.createElement("label");
    numSpan.classList.add("hover--highlight");
    let inputNum = document.createElement("input");
    inputNum.classList.add("input--borders");
    inputNum.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputNum.setAttribute("name", "telephone number");
    inputNum.setAttribute("maxlength", "11");
    inputNum.setAttribute("size", "11");
    let penIcon = document.createElement("i");
    penIcon.classList.add("fas", "fa-pencil-alt", "icon--space__schoolHeaderLeftForm", "icon-pencil-p--size__schoolHeaderLeftForm");
    numSpan.appendChild(inputNum);
    numSpan.appendChild(penIcon);

    let remBtn = document.createElement("button");
    remBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    remBtn.classList.add("btn-noStyle");
    remBtn.setAttribute("onClick", "this.removeNum()");
    let timesIcon = document.createElement("i");
    timesIcon.classList.add("fas", "fa-times", "icon-pencil-p--size__schoolHeaderLeftForm", "icon--space__schoolHeaderLeftForm")
    remBtn.appendChild(timesIcon);

    divWrap.appendChild(numSpan);
    divWrap.appendChild(remBtn);

    document.getElementById("addNum").appendChild(divWrap);
}
```

The following link is a short gif of my error https://gyazo.com/c8689d5fcf76a79d2924f9454ea18e62.

Comment: Can you create runnable demo of your code? That would be easy to debug

Comment: `remBtn.setAttribute("onClick", "this.removeNum()");` – you're passing it a string instead of the function. Even if you change it to a function, using js to add html to an element is an unusual way to use React, and I'm not sure that it will work as you expect even if you pass it the function.

Comment: @ZaidCrouch oh wow, yeah that fixed it; thanks. I also changed it to this.removeNum and the setAttribute to addEventListener() so it now works perfectly.

Comment: @bionia Glad that worked! This is a very un-React way to do things though, as you're basically not using any of the React functionality for handling this sort of case. Is there a specific reason you're doing it this way instead of handling rendering the extra inputs in your render function?